# Contrapositive and the negation of an implication

Tags: discrete-mathematics

What is the contrapositive and the negation of the following implication?

“If $x^2 + x − 2 < 0$, then $x > −2$ and $x < 1$.”

Comment: The *contrapositive* of "if $P$, then $Q$" is : "if $\lnot Q$, then $\lnot P$".

Answer (score 0):

Contrapositive: If $x\leq -2$ or $x\geq1$, then $x^2+x-2\geq 0$.

Negation: $x^2+x-2<0$ and ($x\leq -2$ or $x\geq1$).